# Creating statistically similar sequences

Tags: clustering, simulation, random-generation, distance, similarities

I have to run a test on a program, with some statistical tools to make sure its results are statistically acceptable. This program will take sequences of data information (a vector of integers or symbols with different length) and use some distance metrics (like [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)) to find the distance matrix between these sequences and then cluster them. Now I want to simulate some information to see statistically, how the program is doing. What I have in mind is to create some sequences that are statistically similar and see how does the program cluster them. What option do I have here to do so?